# How to Pass a list as value of parameter in python POST method?

Tags: python, rest, post, python-requests

I am stuck into pass data as list into Ids,  POST ...Please help if anyone knows it. Here is my Python Code
``

```
import json
import requests
from config import api_url

data = [1234, 4214]

payload = json.dumps({
    "Ids": data,
    "serviceProfile": "915"

})



response = requests.request("POST", api_url["url"], headers=header,
                        data=payload, cert=(clientCrt, clientKey))



print(resp.text)
print(resp.status_code)
```

I tried above code and getting this error

```
"httpStatusCode": 400,
    "error": {
        "code": "BAD_PARAMETER",
        "message": "No selected data found" ,
        "reason": "No selected data found" ,
        "moreInfoHref": "https://......../errorCodes/BAD_PARAMETER"
    }
}
```

I just want to passing data as list in POST request and getting API response but its showing 400 .

Comment: Http Response Status 400 - Bad Request The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.

Comment: what is the value of: `api_url["url"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

usually you would send it as a json body

```
result requests.post(url,json={
    "Ids": data,
    "serviceProfile": "915"

})
```

I think is probably what you need ...